# Any reference for the mathematics of Quantum Mechanics with infinite degrees of freedom?

Tags: operator-algebras, book-recommendation, c-star-algebras, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I am looking for a book, or lecture notes or even courses available on YouTube where there is a good and detailed discussion on the mathematical aspects of Quantum Mechanics with infinite degrees of freedom. For what I have seen, this is usually performed using C* algebras formalism for infinite degrees of freedom (like for example infinite tensor products of Von Neumann algebras), so maybe you can help me with that?

Examples of what I am looking for (but I would like something more detailed, these are single chapters from books):

1. "Symmetry Breaking", F. Strocchi, chapter "Mathematical description of infinitely extended quantum systems"
2. "Deterministic Chaos in Infinite Quantum Systems", F. Benatti, chapter " Infinite quantum systems"

Comment: I am pretty sure that in physics stack exchange you have better chances to get a useful answer since this is rather about physics than about mahtematics.

Comment: Oh, ok I will post it there then, thank you!